# Swift: How to implement Markup (Annotations) for PDF like iOS 13's Book app?

Tags: swift, xcode, markup, pdfkit

I have searched everywhere but can't find an answer. The closest I have been able to find is

```
func saveAnnotations_forever() {
        //let documentAttributes = pdfDocument?.documentAttributes
        //let attachmentData = pdfDocument?.dataRepresentation()
        let currentPage = pdfView.currentPage
        let page_index = pdfDocument?.index(for: currentPage!)
        let documentURL = self.pdfDocument?.documentURL// URL to your PDF document.

        // Create a `PDFDocument` object using the URL.
        let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: documentURL!)!

        // `page` is of type `PDFPage`.
        let page = self.pdfDocument!.page(at: page_index!)!

         // Extract the crop box of the PDF. We need this to create an appropriate graphics context.
        let bounds = page.bounds(for: .mediaBox)


        // Create a `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` to use for drawing an image.
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds, format: UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default())

        // This method returns an image and takes a block in which you can perform any kind of drawing.
        let image = renderer.image { (context) in
            // We transform the CTM to match the PDF's coordinate system, but only long enough to draw the page.
            context.cgContext.saveGState()

            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: bounds.height)
            context.cgContext.concatenate(CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1, y: -1))
            page.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context.cgContext)

            context.cgContext.restoreGState()
```

and so on to render an annotation and a PDF page together as an image. However, I cannot search through an annotated page's text (since it was rendered as an image) and I cannot erase my previous annotations once saved. iOS's Book's annotations works very well- I want to achieve that, but how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to save an annotation to a PDF, maybe try this code:

```
// add annotation to the current page
let rect = NSRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 30, height: 30)
let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: rect, forType: .text, withProperties: nil)
pdfView.currentPage?.addAnnotation(annotation)

// save the PDF to file
if let doc = self.document,
   let url = self.document?.documentURL {
    doc.write(to: url)
}
```

You can use the [PDFAnnotation documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfannotation) to further customize the annotation.